# Scalac import language error

Tags: scala, scalac

I'm trying to compile the [AtomicScala](http://www.atomicscala.com/) example:

`scalac AtomicTest.scala`

I get the error:

```
AtomicTest.scala:9: error: not found: object language 
import language.implicitConversions._
       ^
```

I'm a complete novice so any help is much appreciated.
PS Scala compiler version 2.9.2

Comment: SOLUTION: I update scala as per wheaties answer, using the instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/555043/about-installing-scala-2-11-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the evolution of Scala, several things were moved to compiler flags and imports as they were deemed to "advanced" and "complicated" for the general community. This was to streamline the language and reduce complexity for newer developers. This was not the case in Scala 2.9.x. You don't need that import. That said, if you're trying to follow a coding example, why not switch to a more modern version, like 2.11.8?